# How to solve the Error "ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink ..." when installing gulp in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, gulp, gulp-install

I am trying to instal gulp globally. In the beginning I was having issues so I changed the owner of the file from the root to my user.
But Know I am getting this error, and to be honest is my first time working with the terminal to install feature. I would appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:~ anthonyarguello$ npm install --g gulp-cli
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/local/bin/gulp' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js\' -> \'/usr/local/bin/gulp\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/gulp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/anthonyarguello/.npm/_logs/2019-06-30T00_38_52_813Z-debug.log
```

installed gulp!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try : 
sudo npm install --g gulp-cli

Comment: `sudo npm install -g gulp-cli` // `-g` with single dash